# floating point division in WinMips64

Tags: mips, mips64

I am learning about pipelining in WinMips64  and in an example, I am trying to divide two floating point numbers.
Before asking this question I searched thoroughly on Stackoverflow
However, WinMIPS64 don't have much content on StackOverflow.
So I don't know whether I am going in the right direction or not?

**My Try:**

```
.data
A:    .double 10.3
B:    .double 8.2
C:    .double 0.0

      .text
main:
      l.d f4,A(r0)
      l.d f2,B(r0)
      div.d f0,f4,f2
      s.d f0,C(r0)
      halt
```

**QUESTION:**
Can anyone please let me know whether I am doing the floating point division correctly or not? and also suggest some resource to learn WinMips64.

Comment: _"Can anyone please let me know whether I am doing the floating point division correctly or not?"_ Well, does it produce the correct result or not?

Comment: In winmips64 where can I see the registers' content it is a bit different than mars ,however code doesn't produce any errors perhaps I am doing it correctly